# Google Assistant / Ask for a Place is not working :(

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google

I try to request an address using conv.ask(new Place(options)) but it does not seem to work.
Google correctly asks the user for permission, but he never understands any address.

```
Google : Pour vous livrer, je dois d'abord vérifier votre position. Est-ce que je peux récupérer cette information depuis votre compte Google ?
Me : oui
Google : A quelle adresse souhaitez-vous être livré ?
Me : 2 rue Paul Prouteau 92250
Google : Excusez-moi, A quelle adresse souhaitez-vous être livré ?
Me : A mon domicile
Google : Je n'ai toujours pas compris. Dites par exemple : "23 rue Faidherbe à Paris". A quelle adresse souhaitez-vous être livré ?
Me : 23 rue Faidherbe à Paris
Google : Malheureusement, je ne peux pas vous aider.
```

I created my intent on Dialogflow and hosted my code on Firebase Spark plan.

```
app.intent('ask_for_place_detail', (conv) => {
  const options = {
    context: 'Pour vous livrer',
    prompt: 'A quelle adresse souhaitez-vous être livré ?',
  };
  conv.ask(new Place(options));
});


app.intent('ask_for_place_confirmation', (conv, params, place, status) => {
  if (!place) return conv.ask(`Désolé, nous n'avons pas trouvé d'addresse`);
  // the place also carries formattedAddress, and coordinates fields
  const {name} = place;
  if (place.name) conv.ask(`ok, on vous livre à ${name}`);
});
```

I do not see any error in the logs and I think I have enabled the correct Google Map APIs.
Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your place confirmation intent has the following event "`actions_intent_PLACE`"
[Helper functions](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers#place_and_location) need respective events to be handled in the intents while designing in the Dialogflow or other NLP frameworks. If you are using Dialogflow, add this event.

Comment: Thanks, the confirmation intent is well triggered with the "actions_intent_PLACE" event. However google could not reconized the given address. It's maybe a Firebase limition ? I've readed that the free plan is not allowed to contact external servers ? Or maybe an Google Map API is not activated ?

Answer (score 0):

I duplicate my action in English and it's works in the simulator!

So, there is maybe a bug with the French version.